# How to access loaded images in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to share an image using [Expo Sharing](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sharing/) but it throws an error,

```
[Error: Only local file URLs are supported (expected scheme to be 'file', got 'https']
```

This `https` URI is my S3 bucket's, and that's how I fetch uploaded media. I use `<Image />` to display this media, and I want to implement functionality that allows me to share these images out of my app.

When I use `<Image />`, these images are cached/stored/loaded somewhere, and I'm wondering how can I find access them? I've tried doing

```
<Image onLoad={() => console.log(e)}
```

But that doesn't tell me anything other than what the original source URI was.

Comment: have you tried with Image.prefetch(url) and then Image.queryCache(urls) ?

Comment: I have, it just tells me that the image(s) are in memory.. but how do I access that memory to get the `file:/..` link (in the case of android, for instance)?